# How to compute gcd of two polynomials efficiently

Tags: polynomials, factoring, gcd-and-lcm

I have two polynomials $A=x^4+x^2+1$
And $B=x^4-x^2-2x-1$

I need to compute the gcd of $A$ and $B$ but when I do the regular Euclidean way I get fractions and it gets confusing, are you somehow able to use a SylvesterMatrix to find the gcd or am I probably doing something wrong?

I don’t know how to format properly yet so apologies

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/    in particular it's not clear to me whether your x and your X are means to be the same or different variables.

Comment: You have to put `$` signs around the MathJax for the formatting to take effect.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The same variable, auto caps on phone, sorry

Comment: You shouldn't get fractions, any more than you get fractions when using the Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd of two integers.

Comment: I feel like the answer might depend on the ring we're working in. What ring do we suppose the coefficients of $A,B$ come from? If we're allowed to go as far as the complex numbers, then an easy argument would probably involve finding the roots of each and using the fundamental theorem of algebra. EDIT: Though Michael's answer looks even easier... >_>

Comment: @saulspatz we do get fraction coefficients if we want to write the gcd as a Bezout type combination

Comment: @WillJagy Ah, I understand now. I thought the OP meant rational functions.

Comment: @WillJagy Only true if one insists that gcds are (unit-normalized) *monic*. Otherwise we can leave the factor of $2$ in the gcd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most efficiently it's the following.
$$x^4-x^2-2x-1=x^4-(x+1)^2=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x+1).$$
$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1).$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left( 1  \right) } +  \left(  2 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right)  =  \left(  2 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left( 1  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left( 1  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  -  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  $$

.....

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a simpler method?!

We define h=aA+bB (a&b are any constants) as a linear combination of A&B.

Now,the gcd of A&B=gcd of A&h=gcd of B&h.Why?

Because,taking gcd of A&B=c;

h=aA+bB=acA'+bcBb'=c(aA'+bB'),then c is a factor of h also.

Set a=1 & b=-1,so we get rid of the x^4 terms;

h=A-B=$2x^2+2x+2=2(x^2+x+1)$     (1)

Set a=1&b=1,so we get rid of the constant terms;

h=A+B=$2x^4-2x=2x(x^3-1)=2x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$  (2)

Now,both of the linear combinations (1)&(2),

contain $(2x^2+3x-2)$

Then,$(2x^2+3x-2)$ is the gcd.

Comment: "Containing" is imprecise. Better: $\,2\,$ is unit so $\,(A,B) = (A-B,A+B) = A-B\ $ by $\ A-B\mid A+B,\,$ i.e. $\,2(x^2+x+1)\mid 2x(x^3-1)\ \ $